# Task log in Airflow using PapermillOperator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, airflow

I'm running a project using notebooks, for this I end up using PapermillOperator in airflow. However, when using real-time logs within the airflow platform, the prints are not displayed, making it impossible to monitor the execution in real time.

Is there any alternative for notebook prints to be displayed in the airflow log?

I tried to use:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```